# error Retrofit Unauthorized 401

Tags: android, basic-authentication, retrofit2, okhttp

In my android app I need to call a Rest Web service with authantification to the server 
this is a part of my code :

```
  public static final String API_URL = "http://adm-erp-tst1.adm.gov.sa:8001/webservices/rest/mobilesvc/";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
  String credentials = "login" + ":" + "password";
    final String basic =
            "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();


            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", basic)
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .method(original.method(), original.body());
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
```

output Log :

```
Retrofit response onResponse msg : Unauthorized........and .. response code : 401
```

and I am sure that the login and password are correct.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

update:

```
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp
    D/OkHttp: --> POST http://adm-erp-tst1.adm.gov.sa:8001/webservices/rest/mobilesvc/validate_user_login/ http/1.1
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 369
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: {"VALIDATE_USER_LOGIN_input":{"RESTHeader":{"NLSLanguage":"AMERICAN","RespApplication":"SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR","SecurityGroup":"STANDARD","@xmlns":"http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/per/soaprovider/plsql/rest/mobilesvc/header"}}}
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: --> END POST (369-byte body)
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: --> POST http://adm-erp-tst1.adm.gov.sa:8001/webservices/rest/mobilesvc/validate_user_login/ http/1.1
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 369
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Authorization: Basic U1lTQURNSU46aHVsNTU4ODg1OA==
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Accept: text/html
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: {"VALIDATE_USER_LOGIN_input":{"RESTHeader":{"NLSLanguage":"AMERICAN","RespApplication":"SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR","SecurityGroup":"STANDARD","@xmlns":"http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/per/soaprovider/plsql/rest/mobilesvc/header"},"@xmlns":"http://adm-erp-tst1.adm.gov.sa:8001/webservices/rest/mobilesvc/"}}
    05-11 09:28:52.970 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: --> END POST (369-byte body)
    05-11 09:28:53.000 19171-19211/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-11 09:28:53.000 19171-19211/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe184c1e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized http://adm-erp-tst1.adm.gov.sa:8001/webservices/rest/mobilesvc/validate_user_login/ (404ms)
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 13:28:53 GMT
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="__ebsisgrealm__"
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=15
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1462973333124
    05-11 09:28:53.374 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1462973333374
    05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: <ISGServiceFault>
    05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp:   <Code>FND_SOA_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE</Code>
    05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp:   <Message>Invalid username or password..Could not authenticate user / token</Message>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp:   <Resolution>Please pass correct user/token.</Resolution>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: </ISGServiceFault>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (228-byte body)
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized http://adm-erp-tst1.adm.gov.sa:8001/webservices/rest/mobilesvc/validate_user_login/ (404ms)
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 13:28:53 GMT
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="__ebsisgrealm__"
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=15
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1462973333124
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1462973333374
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: <ISGServiceFault>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp:   <Code>FND_SOA_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE</Code>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp:   <Message>Invalid username or password..Could not authenticate user / token</Message>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp:   <Resolution>Please pass correct user/token.</Resolution>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: </ISGServiceFault>
     05-11 09:28:53.375 19171-19269/com.ites.makkahleave.mobileerp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (228-byte body)
```

Comment: Did you enable logs in Retrofit? Verify that the request parameters are correct in the logs, then try to run the same request with curl - this will help locate the issue.

Comment: @Egor  please see the update

Comment: Alright, and does the request work if you pass the same credentials using curl? So far it doesn't look like a Retrofit problem.

Comment: yes it work if I test it with postman